# Angle of rotation of circular object in the Z plane

Tags: matlab, math, image-processing, pattern-matching, feature-extraction

I want to calculate the angle of rotation of this circular object on the z plane (i.e., parallel to the image sensor's plane).

[image: Two Images for calculation of angle of rotation]

I have already tried the following:

1. I used the same algorithm as in the [MATLAB example](http://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/find-image-rotation-and-scale-using-automated-feature-matching.html). I tried changing the features detected (SURF, BRISK, MinEigen) to find feature points.
   *I did not get proper output, there were incorrect angles as result. I guess the problem with this was that not many feature points were detected on my wheel rim.*
2. I tried to locate the notch (which I have circled in red for display) using [normxcorr2](http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/normxcorr2.html). If the notch's position is known, using geometry I can calculate the angle of rotation. 
   *Here too, enough features are not detected therefore I am not able to determine the angle correctly.*  Sometimes there is false location detected for the notch.

Can you suggest any other method to calculate the angle of rotation? (In the images I have [uploaded on dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/q9yb53o8matsrbr/AACjC2a7LJcNvjOb9whacflda?dl=0), the angle of rotation is around 75 degrees (*apparent from the position of notch*))

Comment: Not sure if this will get you great results, but you could compute the centers of the images. Then transform them to polar coordinates via these centers and use circular convolution to cross correlate the polar images.

Comment: I have a similar problem, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I would propose the following algorithm:

1. Extract your circular object by applying some threshold.
2. Calculate the center. This can be done by using some circle fitting or using the center of gravity.
3. Now, extract the gray values on circles in distance to the center where you expect your notch to be.
4. By finding the darkest areas in your extracted values, you should get the rotation angle.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried what you said. However, I am not able to extract only the four dark areas / notch. [This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n01b446xc63kdk7/Binarized_Img.bmp?dl=0) is what I am getting as binarized output.